# windows C++ opening printer with documentproperties get C6836 "Write Overrun" Code analysis warning

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

In the following code:

```
// If GetPrinter didn't fill in the DEVMODE, try to get it by calling
// DocumentProperties...
if (pi2->pDevMode == NULL)
{
    dwNeeded = DocumentProperties(NULL, hPrinter,
        printerName,
        NULL, NULL, 0);

    if (dwNeeded <= 0)
    {
        GlobalFree(pi2);
        ClosePrinter(hPrinter);
        return FALSE;
    }

    pDevMode = (DEVMODE *)GlobalAlloc(GPTR, dwNeeded);
    if (pDevMode == NULL)
    {
        GlobalFree(pi2);
        ClosePrinter(hPrinter);
        return FALSE;
    }

    lFlag = DocumentProperties(NULL, hPrinter,
        printerName,
        pDevMode, NULL,
        DM_OUT_BUFFER);

    if (lFlag != IDOK || pDevMode == NULL)
    {
        GlobalFree(pDevMode);
        GlobalFree(pi2);
        ClosePrinter(hPrinter);
        return FALSE;
    }

    pi2->pDevMode = pDevMode;
}
```

On the line

```
lFlag = DocumentProperties(NULL, hPrinter,
printerName,
pDevMode, NULL,
DM_OUT_BUFFER);
```

When I run Visual Studio 2012 "Code analysis" feature it throws warning:

C6386   Write overrun   Buffer overrun while writing to 'pDevMode':  the writable size is 'dwNeeded' bytes, but '220' bytes might be written. Invalid write to 'pDevMode', (outside its writable range)

The code functions fine, but wondering how to fix this warning from occurring (preferably without disabling warning)

The help page for this error does not seem to apply (or I can't figure how it does) http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev11.query?appId=Dev11IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(C6386)&rd=true

Comment: one piece of microsoft software tells you to use the return value of `DocumentProperties` as buffer size, because it can be larger than `sizeof(DEVMODE)`, another piece of microsoft software tells you to use `DEVMODE`. how about using the largest of those two sizes. accommodating schizophrenic software can be easy, u c!

Comment: as a general observation, the code shown suffers from needless redundancy. do cleanup in destructors. use C++ instead of just C.

Answer (score 1):

The SAL annotation for DocumentProperties cannot express that DEVMODE is a structure than might be larger than its declared size.  The function doesn't also take an argument that states the passed size of the DEVMODE.  Nor does the structure have a single field that states the size.  So an annotation like `__out_bcount_opt` or `__out_bcount_part` could not be used.

It is an issue with all winapi functions that take a DEVMODE.  It is a structure that dates from the stone age, long before SAL was ever on the horizon.  If Microsoft could do it all over again then they would do this differently.  Too late now.

Nothing you can do about it beyond knowing that you got it right and the tool got it wrong.  It is just a warning.